# Custom post type archive page for multiple post types

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, variables

Hi I am working on a archive page which I can use for multiple custom post types. I need to make a variable in the `$args` array which can change to the `post_type` name on the basis of 
`<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>`

So something like this:

```
<?php

$post_type = post_type_archive_title();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
);

query_posts($args); ?>
```

But this doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Is `$post_type === CPT registered name` ?

Comment: You mean I need to take another name for my variable?

Comment: No, i'm wondering if the value returned by `post_type_archive_title();` is equal to CPT registered name

Comment: Yes post_type_archive_title(); is equal to CPT registered name.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_archive_title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WordPress Codex:

> **Function Reference/post type archive title**
>
> This is optimized for archive.php and archive-{posttype}.php template
>   files for displaying the title of the post type.

"Title of post type" is the label, not the post type registered name.

You can get the registered post type name using `get_queried_object();` like this:

```
<?php
 $obj = get_queried_object();
 $post_type = $obj->name;
?>
```

I see in your `$args` array, the `caller_get_posts`, if you are using WordPress 3.1+, i suggest you to use `ignore_sticky_posts` that replaced the previous one. Look [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) ( pagination parameters ).

Maybe i'm wrong maybe not, if you have any problems, reply here : )

Comment: I've tried it with get_queried_obj(); But that gave me the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_queried_obj()

Comment: sorry, sorry! my fault! update the answer